# Por que typeof 1 === "number" retorna true se tudo que está delimitado por aspas é uma string?

Tags: javascript, string, tipagem, operadores

Criei uma função que recebe um *array* de elementos e retorna outro *array* somente com os números presentes no *array* recebido como parâmetro.

Cheguei a esta resolução:

```js
function filtrarNumeros(array) {
  return array.filter(item => typeof item === "number")
}

console.log(filtrarNumeros(["Javascript", 1, "3", "Web", 20])) // retornará [1, 20]
```

Percebi que mesmo delimitado por aspas o "number" retorna `true`. Foi então que fiz um pequeno teste:

```
console.log(typeof 1  === "number") // retorna true
```

Por que `"number"` retorna `true` se o que está delimitado por aspas tecnicamente é uma `string`?

Comment: Porque `typeof ` retorna o tipo de uma variável como _string_, logo `typeof 1` é `"number"`, por isso resultado é `true`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vamos olhar a [tabela de precedência dos operadores do JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Como ali tem 2 operadores oque será executado primeiro é o que tem maior precedência. Portanto o código que você usou é o mesmo que:

```
console.log((typeof 1) === "number")
```

E o que o [operador `typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) retorna? Uma `string` com o nome do tipo, no caso claramente é um número, portanto retorna `"number"`, e agora fica fácil perceber que os valores são iguais, certo?

Decompondo ficaria:

```
console.log("number" === "number")
```

E o [operador `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) resulta em `true` quando duas coisas são exatamente iguais. Finalizando a decomposição:

```
console.log(true)
```

É matemática pura, com um elemento que só tem em programação.

```js
console.log((typeof 1));
console.log((typeof 1) === "number");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/NumberName.js).

Answer (score 10):

## Explicação

Você não esta comparando o número 1 com a string `"number"`, você esta comparando a saída de `typeof 1` que é a string `"number"` com `"number"`, por isso o resultado `true`. Segue abaixo o mesmo exemplo só que separado em partes para exemplificar.

## Exemplo

```js
var valor = 1;
var textoDoTipo = "number"
var typeofDeUm = typeof 1;

console.log('Valor: ', valor);
console.log('Texto do tipo: ', textoDoTipo);
console.log('"Typeof" de Um: ', typeofDeUm);
console.log('"Typeof" de Um é igual ao texto de um? ', typeofDeUm === typeofDeUm);
```

Answer (score -1):

Você está comparando a saída gerada por `typeof 1`, que é number, com a string `number`. Quando identificado, o tipo do valor `1` é uma String. Logo o que o código compara é `console.log("number" === "number")`, por isso resulta `true`.